# Hbase and Zookeeper EndOfStreamException

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

this Exception is always appears

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13da73a3622010a, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

There was this issue with Zookeeper which got fixed in 3.4.5.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1582

Comment: i downloaded the last version 3.4.5 and replace with the old version of hbase library  the same problem happened ,
note :: we made zookeeper managed by hbase (i.e zookeeper not in separate server)

Comment: I am getting this problem in a test with `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster` version `1.2.2` which depends on `org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper` version `3.4.6`.